# React Native ScrollView Crashes on Android APK

Tags: android, react-native, apk, scrollview, release

My app is working as expected in the debug mode

```
react-native run-android
```

but in the release build

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

The app launches fine and I can navigate to all the pages, but whenever I try to scroll or press any view inside a ScrollView, it crashes.  For example, in the code below, the HomeHeader component has two buttons that work well, but whenever I touch anything inside the ScrollView, Unfortunately it crashes. My code is as follow:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
  <HomeHeader/>
  <ScrollView>
      <SomeComponents/>
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Dependencies

```
"react-native": "^0.58.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.10"
```

Error Log

> Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched
>   03-20 21:42:49.156 21328 21372 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
>   03-20 21:42:49.156 21328 21372 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.munasabat, PID: 21328
>   03-20 21:42:49.156 21328 21372 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched, stack:

Comment: Can you please add the error log?

Comment: I did added the error log, check it out.

Comment: I feel that something must have gone wrong in the build-process. I see `libfingersense.so was not loaded` in your error logs. There might be something going on with that.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: I did added the actual code check it out @VinayakB

Comment: thanks @IanRehwinkel, I will try to look into that too.

Comment: I would also try not using the swiper and see if that's what is causing the problem (since it uses a scrollview as well)

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the Swiper because, I have a Scrollview in another screen where there is no Swiper and it still crushes. and anything outside the scrollview works fine, for example in that screen the header has two buttons that work as expected so the problem is with the Scrollview.

Comment: Have you run it with debugger? As far as i see there is a stated problem with : 'libfingersense_wrapper: libfingersense.so was not loaded' @AhmedImam

Comment: yeah, I did it is working fine in a debug mode, the only problem is on the released build.

Comment: After editing some views, I got a different error now, I just updated the question.

Comment: There is a bug in Android on version 1.0.14 (react-native-gesture-handler), which is fixed on 1.0.15, but has the same issue on iOS as on later versions. Use **`"react-native": "^0.58.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.0.9"`**

Comment: @JonGoodwin thanks man, that was the issue, actually I was using "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.10",  I upgrade it to "1.1.0" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug, found in `Android` version <= `1.0.14` (of `react-native-gesture-handler`), which is fixed in `1.0.15`, but has the same issue in `IOS` and in later versions.
Use (up to date versions where *possible*):

```
 "react-native": "^0.58.0"
 "react-native-gesture-handler" "^1.1.0"
 "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
```